controller action iterates, thereby generating an N+1 condition
A controller action that creates multiple objects within a loop is a candidate for N+1 queries.  Yet, the the following segment
shop_id = section.shop_id
section_id = section.id
serving_table_id = section.serving_table.id
range = 1..i
range.each do |i|
  @cover = Cover.create(shop_id: shop_id, section_id: section_id, serving_table_id: serving_table_id, name: i )      
end

event though the attributes to be saved are defined before the iteration block,
is generating via prosopite gem an N+1 query detection,
for each of the shop, parti and serving_table objects.
Not being a query for a collection, includes would be inapplicable.
How does one avoid N+1 queries in this instance?

your solution is insert_all/upsert_all, and serving_table_id = section.serving_table_id instead of serving_table.id

It's hard to ignore the major bug in this code which is that you're just assigning @cover over and over. Stop using #each for everything and use the appriate methods like #map instead of looping and modifying external variables.

The ActiveRecord::Base#insert_all (https://apidock.com/rails/v7.1.3.4/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/insert_all) can take an array of hashes to create
shop_id = section.shop_id
section_id = section.id
serving_table_id = section.serving_table.id
range = 1..i

Cover.insert_all(
  range.map do |i|
    { shop_id: shop_id, section_id: section_id, serving_table_id: serving_table_id, name: i }
  end
)

Be careful of statement rollback in case one is invalid.

This method is the one missing from every write-up I have seen regarding solving N+1 queries.

Agreed!
The "safe" solution (but slower) is often to use create() with an array. That is basically a wrapper for .each{ create(_1 )}, but encapsulates the logic of creating multiple. Then wrapping it into a transaction, to handle rollbacks.

yes, mileage varies.  In the above case, the parameters come from a different method, which has resolved without doubt the validity of parameters, thus no possible fails of long-winded logic.

You're erraneously assuming that there is one single simple cure-all solution for every scenario.
N+1 queries on read are a relatively simple problem to solve as you can just load the related rows through a join or a separate query with few side effects.
Handing mass inserting/updating/upserting records is not an easy problem.
You need to carefully consider if you can forgo validations and callbacks and use insert_all / update_all / upsert_all in a single query or if you actually need to handle each record separately.
The key factors in deciding here is if the operation is dealing with user input and can be expected to fail, how you're going to handle errors and the perfomance requirements.
Then you have to consider if this can be offloaded into a background job so that the web thead (and the user behind the screen) doesn't have to wait for it to complete which adds the headaches of dealing with an asyncronous process.

This is sage advice. Validation could possibly still be performed without N concerns, depending on the validations and associated data, most callbacks cannot. If you need to implement this functionality (i.e. insert_all) I would highly recommend running it through a service object that can perform the necessary validation calls and implement its own means of issuing callbacks if required.

@engineersmnky the issue with validations is mostly dealing with uniqueness. Not only will it create an extra query but if you're iterating across the records before inserting and validating them you'll get false positives.

Agreed. My other concern regarding validations and why I used the word possibly is the default presence validations for belongs_to, obviously does not cause the same uniqueness concerns but will cause N queries to ensure referential integrity. We could obviously modify this to a single query but would then need to determine the failing record(s), unless failing an entire batch without specific context is acceptable.

You can use activerecord-import gem
shop_id = section.shop_id
section_id = section.id
serving_table_id = section.serving_table.id
range = 1..i
covers = []

range.each do |i|
  covers << Cover.new(shop_id: shop_id, section_id: section_id, serving_table_id: serving_table_id, name: i )      
end

Cover.import convers

